# Save deep network and change its central layer in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I built an autoencoder in TensorFlow. It has 5 hidden layers. I trained the network and I now wish to save it on some external file.

Later, I would like to load the autoencoder back and modify its central layer. Then I would like to run the autoencoder on some input data.

Here my code for the autoencoder. I have inserted some `saver` lines where I think they may help me save the model. However, I am not sure how to reload the saved model and most importantly how to modify its central layer.

```
input = ### some data
output = input

tf.reset_default_graph()

num_inputs=501    
num_hid1=250
num_hid2=100
num_hid3=50
num_hid4=num_hid2
num_hid5=num_hid1
num_output=num_inputs
lr=0.01
actf=tf.nn.tanh

X=tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[None,num_inputs])
initializer=tf.variance_scaling_initializer()

w1=tf.Variable(initializer([num_inputs,num_hid1]),dtype=tf.float32)
w2=tf.Variable(initializer([num_hid1,num_hid2]),dtype=tf.float32)
w3=tf.Variable(initializer([num_hid2,num_hid3]),dtype=tf.float32)
w4=tf.Variable(initializer([num_hid3,num_hid4]),dtype=tf.float32)
w5=tf.Variable(initializer([num_hid4,num_hid5]),dtype=tf.float32)
w6=tf.Variable(initializer([num_hid5,num_output]),dtype=tf.float32)

b1=tf.Variable(tf.zeros(num_hid1))
b2=tf.Variable(tf.zeros(num_hid2))
b3=tf.Variable(tf.zeros(num_hid3))
b4=tf.Variable(tf.zeros(num_hid4))
b5=tf.Variable(tf.zeros(num_hid5))
b6=tf.Variable(tf.zeros(num_output))

hid_layer1=actf(tf.matmul(X,w1)+b1)
hid_layer2=actf(tf.matmul(hid_layer1,w2)+b2)
hid_layer3=actf(tf.matmul(hid_layer2,w3)+b3)
hid_layer4=actf(tf.matmul(hid_layer3,w4)+b4)
hid_layer5=actf(tf.matmul(hid_layer4,w5)+b5)
output_layer=tf.matmul(hid_layer5,w6)+b6

loss=tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(output_layer-X))

optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(lr)
train=optimizer.minimize(loss)

init=tf.global_variables_initializer()

num_epoch=100000
batch_size=150

saver = tf.train.Saver()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    for epoch in range(num_epoch):

        sess.run(train,feed_dict={X:input})

        train_loss=loss.eval(feed_dict={X:input})
        print("epoch {} loss {}".format(epoch,train_loss))


    results=output_layer.eval(feed_dict={X:input})
    saver.save(sess, 'my_test_model')
```

EDIT:

In reply to @mujjiga 's answer, in fact what I have to is to chop off the encoder part of this autoencoder. And then use the remaining decoder to decode a new set of `hid_layer3` features.

Comment: when you say modify do you intend to chop off and use for prediction or you intend to modify the computation graph and retrain ?

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to chop off the decoder part and use the encoder to get the latent representation of your input (normal application of autoencoders), then you can do the following (if `hid_layer3` represents the latent representation / output of encoder)

```
tf.reset_default_graph()

num_inputs=501    
num_hid1=250
num_hid2=100
num_hid3=50
num_hid4=num_hid2
num_hid5=num_hid1
num_output=num_inputs
lr=0.01
actf=tf.nn.tanh

output = np.random.rand(100,num_inputs)

X=tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[None,num_inputs])
initializer=tf.variance_scaling_initializer()

w1=tf.Variable(initializer([num_inputs,num_hid1]),dtype=tf.float32)
w2=tf.Variable(initializer([num_hid1,num_hid2]),dtype=tf.float32)
w3=tf.Variable(initializer([num_hid2,num_hid3]),dtype=tf.float32)
w4=tf.Variable(initializer([num_hid3,num_hid4]),dtype=tf.float32)
w5=tf.Variable(initializer([num_hid4,num_hid5]),dtype=tf.float32)
w6=tf.Variable(initializer([num_hid5,num_output]),dtype=tf.float32)

b1=tf.Variable(tf.zeros(num_hid1))
b2=tf.Variable(tf.zeros(num_hid2))
b3=tf.Variable(tf.zeros(num_hid3))
b4=tf.Variable(tf.zeros(num_hid4))
b5=tf.Variable(tf.zeros(num_hid5))
b6=tf.Variable(tf.zeros(num_output))

hid_layer1=actf(tf.matmul(X,w1)+b1)
hid_layer2=actf(tf.matmul(hid_layer1,w2)+b2)
hid_layer3=actf(tf.matmul(hid_layer2,w3)+b3)
hid_layer4=actf(tf.matmul(hid_layer3,w4)+b4)
hid_layer5=actf(tf.matmul(hid_layer4,w5)+b5)
output_layer=tf.matmul(hid_layer5,w6)+b6

saver = tf.train.Saver()
with tf.Session() as sess:
  saver.restore(sess,  'my_test_model')
  print("Model restored.")    
  x = sess.run(hid_layer3, feed_dict={X:output})
  assert x.shape[1] == hid_layer3.shape[1]
```

As you can see you still need to define the model architecture, but load the weight from the saved model.

Comment: Yes that's almost what I need. I actually need only the "decoder" part. Assume that somehow (details are unimportant here) I obtain a set of hid_layer3 that is different from the ones I obtained with the trained autoencoder. I would like to see what type of output these new hid_layer3 produce

Comment: it will be totally different based on the data used to train, no:of epochs it was trained on. I would suggest to check the vector similarity of `hid_layer3` of those two different models. You can use euclidian distance,  cosin similarity etc.

Comment: thank you, anyway as I said it doesn't matter if the new hid_layer3 is simlar or not to the original one. Could you still show me how to decode the new hid_layer3, using the previously trained decoder? thanks